# Meaning of ぐらいでいいのでは in 「三回ぐらい噛んで飲み込めるぐらいでいいのでは？」

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs

Can you tell me what ぐらいでいいのでは means?
Also, I don't understand why potential form of the verb is used in this sentence
Can you help me to translate this sentence?

Context: The questioner asked how to eat "elegantly" while you talk to someone, and the responder wrote:

> 口に運ぶ量を少なめにするといいと思いますよ。三回ぐらい噛んで飲み込める**ぐらいでいいのでは**？

Comment: Can you let us know how do you understand (part of) this sentence, and why do you think potential form is unsuitable here?

Comment: I don't understand the ぐらいでいい part

Comment: Without further context, it would be impossible to discuss why the potential form is being used.

Comment: The questioner asked how to eat "elegantly" while you talk to someone, and the responder wrote "口に運ぶ量を少なめにするといいと思いますよ。三回ぐらい噛んで飲み込めるぐらいでいいのでは？"

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your additional info, OP, the question is now answerable.

So, the overall context is:

> Person A: "How should/could one eat elegantly while speaking to another?"
>
> Person B: 「[口]{くち}に[運]{はこ}ぶ[量]{りょう}を[少]{すく}なめにするといいと[思]{おも}いますよ。[三回]{さんかい}ぐらい[噛]{か}んで[飲]{の}み[込]{こ}める**ぐらいでいい**のでは？ 」

「～～ぐらいでいいのでは？」 is an expression of **suggesting a method** for an action.  It gives a ***rough*** ***idea*** of what should suffice in achieving a good result, which should explain why 「ぐらい = "approximately"」 is being used.

「～～でいいのでは？」 = 「～～でいいのでは**ないでしょうか**？」 if that helps you understand the phrase better.  It is a way of asking the question: "Wouldn't ~~ suffice?", "Wouldn't ~~ be good enough?"

What is the rough idea being suggested?  It is "bringing a somewhat small amount of food into your mouth at a time so that ***one could swallow*** it only after chewing it about 3 times".

To say "***one could swallow***", it uses the potential form 「飲み込める」.

Answer (score 1):

That ぐらい is 位, or "degree". So, translating it word by word, it's "Isn't it enough by the degree in which you can bite it three times and swallow it?". What it says is eventually "I think it's enough when you do it so that you could bite it three times and swallow it".